# Build a Pandas pd.tseries.offsets from string

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sampling

Pandas provides a method for DataFrame and Timeseries named `resample`.

see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html

and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

this method have a parameter named `rule`

so we can do (to resample with 2 hours sampling period) :

```
ts2 = ts.resample('2H', how='mean')
```

I'm looking for a way to convert this `'2H'` string parameter to a Pandas `pd.tseries.offsets`

(because

```
In [10]: ts2.index.freq
Out[10]: <2 * Hours>
```

and

```
In [11]: type(ts2.index.freq)
Out[11]: pandas.tseries.offsets.Hour
```

I was looking for a method like:

```
pd.tseries.offsets.from_string('2H')
```

but it doesn't seems to exists.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [13]: from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

In [14]: to_offset('2H')
Out[14]: <2 * Hours>
```

though you dont' really need to do this, e.g. resample will call this to convert string inputs.
And you can simply call it with the constructed frequency, e.g. `df.resample(pd.offsets.Hour(2)....)` as well.

Comment: I understand why you can believe that I don't need this, but I need it to get a timedelta (for Javascript plotting using HighCharts) from "rule"... so that's the reason I need this `to_offset` method. Thanks again for your quick answer.